# Angular Animation - animate children one by one

Tags: angular, animation

My example - [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a2yvjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I need to animate 3 elements one by one. For the last two elements, I need to save the state.

Behavior -

- execute animation for first element ->animation is done, element disappeared
- next step - element hidden - execute animation for second element - element saved state for the last frame
- last step - element hidden - animation for the third element - element saved state for the last frame

Current behavior -

- execute animation for first element -> animation is done, element disappeared

then the animation for the last two elements is executed in parallel

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy you resolve yourself. In general, if we want to make an animation step by step. it's util to have an array.

Imagine you has an array and an index like

```
index=-1
states=[false,false,false]
```

A function like

```
   animationDone()
   {
      index++
      if (index<states.length)
        states[index]=true
   }
```

allow you write some like

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of [0,1,2] let i = index">
    <div class="card"
      [@move]="states[i]"
      (@move.done)="index==i && animationDone()"
    >
      {{ item }}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

or

```
<div class="card"
[@move]="states[0]"
(@move.done)="index==0 && animationDone()"
>
one
</div>
<div class="card"
[@move]="states[1]"
(@move.done)="index==1 && animationDone()"
>
two
</div>
<div class="card"
[@move]="states[2]"
(@move.done)="index==2 && animationDone()"
>
three
</div>
```

And our simple animation:

```
  animations:[
    trigger('move',[
      state('false',style({opacity:0})),
      state('true',style({opacity:1})),
      transition('false => true',[
      animate('1000ms'),
    ])])
  ]
```

Well, we can make some more complex. Imagine an animation like

```
  animations:[
    trigger('move',[
      state('0-false',style({opacity:0})),
      state('0-true',style({opacity:1})),
      state('1-false',style({transform:'scale(0)'})),
      state('1-true',style({transform:'scale(1)'})),
      state('2-false',style({transform:'translateY(-200%)'})),
      state('2-true',style({transform:'translateY(0)'})),
      transition('0-false => 0-true',[animate('1000ms')]),
      transition('1-false => 1-true',[animate('1000ms')]),
      transition('2-false => 2-true',[animate('1000ms')])
    ])
  ]
```

Now we can use the same, but now the [@move] is like `"0-"+states[0]`

```
<div class="card"
[@move]="'0-'+states[0]"
(@move.done)="index==0 && animationDone()"
>
one
</div>
<div class="card"
[@move]="'1-'+states[1]"
(@move.done)="index==1 && animationDone()"
>
two
</div>
<div class="card"
[@move]="'2-'+states[2]"
(@move.done)="index==2 && animationDone()"
>
three
</div>
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nhgzjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: In SO many people give our time for the simple pleasure of helping, but there is no obligation to do so. If your stackblitz had been something less complex, surely more people would have been encouraged to respond

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Great example. But why my stackblitz is complex?

Comment: well, really reading carefoully it's not so comple, Sinceryly, I surrender when see your "img" (in base64).- in stackblitz you can use lorem picsum (e.g. `<img src='https://picsum.photos/100/50'>`- to get an imagen of 100x50. The audio tag it's not important to the app. Futhermore, the animations in Angular are a bit hard for me. :(

Comment: Ahh, -> <img src='https://picsum.photos/100/50'>, because I can't find a way to add images to assets. and by stock URL — png images with placeholder background

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who did not answer - it helps me to become better. )))

I just had to set the timings. Of course, this is not the best solution but excludes listening - animation.start & animation.done

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the source if anyone needs an example